# Limiting a model in a has_many assossiation with its parent method integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named course with an attribute of capacity how can I limit its child model named course_enrollment which is a rich model between course and students with the attribute of its parent ?(I mean the capacity attribute mentioned above)I am working on Ruby on Rails and it is my first question here in stack over flow

Comment: By limiting you mean in numbers? like only 20 students can enroll to a certain course for example ?

Comment: Yeah i want to set a capacity in my course model and then limit the nubmber of students in the rich join named course enrollment which belongs to courses . Is that clear . It is limiting by a method of its parent model not just a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `courses` have an attribute called `capacity`, try something like this

```
def Course
  has_many :enrollments
  validate :course_capacity

  def cource_capacity
    if enrollments.size > capacity
      errors.add(:base, 'is already full')
    end
  end
end
```

Also don't forget to add

```
validates_associated :course
```

To the enrollment model

Comment: I get it must be an integer for max_enrollment , capacity in my case it doesnt recognize the capacity method

Comment: ok maybe change it to a proc, like `length: {maximum: ->{capacity}}`

Comment: Proc works just like that ? I just use my attribute in that curly with lambda ?

Comment: Btw tnc for the effort

Comment: stupid question, is capacity not an integer? or empty?

Comment: ok nvm, i tested it on a project i have, i guess we'll have to go with a custom method, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Tnx dude ill try that

Comment: I changed `count` to `size`, cause `count` won't see the new enrollment before it's saved

Comment: Tnx dude it works when i want to create or update the parent but it doesnt work when i try it from enrollments it just adds and doesnt validate the validdation

Comment: add `validates_associated :course` to the enrollments model

Comment: Tnx mohammad. Appreciate the effort :) peace